# about bufferGeometry needsUpdate

Tags: three.js

```js
var positions = new Float32Array(geometry.__directGeometry.vertices.length * 3);
geometry._bufferGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3).copyVector3sArray(geometry.__directGeometry.vertices));
```

This is valid

```
geometry._bufferGeometry.getAttribute('position').copyVector3sArray(geometry.__directGeometry.vertices);
geometry._bufferGeometry.getAttribute('position').needsUpdate = true;
```

this is invalid, don't know why, three.js v119

Comment: You are not supposed to work with `__directGeometry`. It's a private attribute and not meant for public access.

Comment: geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; Doesn't work, so I used this.

Comment: If the geometry is of type `BufferGeometry`, there is no property `verticesNeedUpdate`.

Comment: it's geometry,not BufferGeometry.